# Why are my Photoshop exported images much larger in dimensions than I indicated my source file?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cc-2018

I edited a photo with a 97x81 inch dimension and about 230ppi in Photoshop (to send to a print company because I need this thing printed on a tarp). When it came out, I checked the size by opening the image on PS and was shocked to see that it was at 151x140 or something like that, and suddenly it was only at 72ppi.

What gives? What am I doing wrong with the exporting? I just need it to stay the exact same size (97x81 in) and not get bigger or anything, because it won't fit on the tarp anymore.

I flatten the image, use "Export As", and then choose JPEG. I also use CC 2018 if ever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't "Export". Save as.. jpg.

The "Export" command assumes the image is for screen display and therefore eliminates any data which may be superfluous for screen rendering, such as a PPI setting. Using Save As, a jpg will retain the PPI setting.

Comment: IT WORKS. YOU'RE A LIFESAVER (and a job saver at that). Many thanks.